# Information about Facebook logins and unique pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to learn how to implement login into a website but I've heard that I shouldn't make a custom script unless I really know what I'm doing.
A better alternative I've hard is to just use Facebook login. I've looked over the docs but I'm still confused on something. I want to store additional information about the user (not just their facebook profile information) and I need to use that information to generate unique pages when they're logged in.

I am also wondering if the additional information I save about them will be just as secure as their facebook information or if it will be more vunerable.

If someone could guide me in the right direction with direct answers or useful articles I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand exactly what you are asking... Once you have authenticated your users, you'll be able to extract any information they have made available to you (according to the permissions they have granted your app). With regard to information being vulnerable; All the information held in your DB is "vulnerable" in the same way - I don't see any separation between profile info/other info.

Comment: Just so I understand clearly, every user when they log in get a unique id correct? So I have to make a table in my database that stores that id, then any information about them that I want. So whenever they log in I'm assuming they get the same id every time and their information will be ready available from the database. @Lix

Comment: Yep - a Facebook user ID is a unique identifier that will never change. If Facebook were to change a users ID it would be like gmail changing someones email address :P Not gonna happen!

Comment: Thank you very much for that, it clarifies more things. I don't learn very well from docs as I tend to just get lost in it all.

Comment: You can use the user id as a primary key in your DB and you won't have to worry about duplicates. Keep in mind though, that new applications have an app scoped user id - this means that the same user might have different ID's per application. The ID's won't change within the scope of the application though...

Comment: @Lix One more question, could someone use the user ID for malicious intentions? I use the latest and presumably most secure database connections but if someone got a hold of the user ID could they do anything with it?

Comment: Hmm... I don't think I know what you mean... I know for example that [Mark.Z's Facebook ID is #4](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=4) but there is not much more that I can do with it. In order to do **anything** with the Facebook API a valid access token must be used - this token is the thing that could be used maliciously since it could be used to perform actions on behalf of another user.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing access tokens in your DB (partially because they expire so regularly); If someone was to get into your DB and found there a collection of tokens relating to Facebook ID's **then** some very malicious actions could be performed....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78028/discussion-between-mr-smithyyy-and-lix).

Comment: Sorry friend, can't do chat ATM. Feel free to continue commenting here for now - I'll answer once I have some spare time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the docs for [login with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3) and try out the sample code provided. That will give you a clear idea how to integrate Facebook login in your website.
In order to integrate login with Facebook you will first require an app id which is quite simple to [create](https://developers.facebook.com/?advanced_app_create=true). Once you have the FB app id, you can integrate the login bit. Once the user successfully logs in, you should get back an app-scoped user id and as suggested by Lix use that as the primary key. Also, after user logs in, you can may be present a form where you collect additional data and save that against the user id in the database.

Regarding the security of the information, it really depends how and where you store it.